# Why does my Apple Pencil produce different brush strokes than my mouse in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, mac, ipad

I’m working through the 2021 release of *Adobe Photoshop Classroom in a Book* for my digital imaging class. One of the lessons is on the Mixer Brush tool. I decided to connect my Mac to my iPad Pro using Sidecar so that I could use my Apple Pencil (I find it easier to use than my mouse for these types of tasks).

It worked fine at first, but eventually I ran into an issue where my brush strokes looked nothing like what the textbook showed. I tried switching to my mouse, and it solved the issue. As far as I can tell, the input device is the only difference; the settings should be the same. I’ve included screenshots showing the results I’m getting and my brush settings. In case it helps, I’ve also added a couple of pictures of the relevant page in the textbook. Also, my Apple Pencil is the 2nd generation version.

Can anyone tell me why I’m getting different results with the Apple Pencil? And how can I can fix it so that the brush strokes look the same as with the mouse? Thanks!

*screenshot showing brush strokes:*
[image: brush strokes]
*screenshots showing Brush Settings panel:*
[image: Brush Settings panel]

*pictures of relevant textbook page:*
[image: relevant textbook page]

[Note: I wasn’t sure if this is the correct place to post this question, so apologies if it is!]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Apple Pencil.. but I'd suspect it's some *System* setting for the pencil, not any Photoshop setting causing the issue. If this were a Wacom tablet, I'd be looking at the Wacom settings.

Comment: Post duplicated at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429905/why-does-my-apple-pencil-produce-different-brush-strokes-than-my-mouse-in-photos Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)